# Circuit for RF Splitter

Tags: equipment-design, amplifier

Does anyone know of any resources which describe how to design a circuit with one RF input and multiple (at least 6) RF outputs, whereby the signal strength of each output matches (does not exceed and is not less than) the input signal strength? I'm thinking this would be some kind of self limiting amplifier, but not sure the best way to think about this. For non-RF there would be some classic OmpAmp circuits which may work. But I'm talking UHF and above here.

NB: Must be 50ohm input and output.

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to hamSE. Please tell us the frequency range over which you want the device to operate. "UHF and above" is too general to permit a specific answer.

Comment: IMO this question falls on the badly-defined border between ham.SE and electronics.SE, but given that the OP has also asked the question on electronics.SE, we should close this one.

Comment: @rclocher3 I was thinking about that. However, since [the question there](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/549851/circuit-for-rf-splitter) was closed, I would rather not at this time. However, if enough folks flag, downvote, etc. it for the reasons in the comments there, it might automatically be closed. *I am not saying whether or not I agree*. This site is mostly moderated by the users here, not moderators (as is being discussed [**here**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ham.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirement to operate down to 1-MHz, it seems likely you will have to use a lumped-element design. [Ferrite Transformers Fuel Broadband Power Dividers](https://www.mwrf.com/technologies/passive-components/article/21845377/trm-microwave-ferrite-transformers-fuel-broadband-power-dividers), by Dr. Karen Kocharyan, gives useful information on lumped-element divider design.

Commercially available units, like the MiniCircuits [ZFSC-6-110](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=ZFSC-6-110), suggest that a design approaching your requirements may be achievable. Judging from the specifications of this product, it seems likely that it comprises multiple instantiations of the company's wideband "core and wire" transformer products, for which the company provides S-parameters. The company also provides a wide range of MMIC amplifiers which could make up the "loss" encountered at each output port as a result of the division of input power.

Resistive power splitters, described at [Microwaves101](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/resistive-power-splitters), are a lossier solution but may fit your needs since you already plan to recover the "lost" power through amplification.